# Android sound processing

Tags: java, android, audio, mfcc, javax.sound.sampled

I have a Java application that computes the MFCC coefficients of an audio file by reading it into an AudioInputStream object and then writing it into a Byte array.

```
public double[] convertsignal(File signalfile) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(signalfile);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int read;
    byte[] buff = new byte[2048];
    while ((read=audioInputStream.read(buff, 0, 2048)) > 0)
    {
        out.write(buff, 0, read);
    }
    out.flush();
    byte[] audioBytes = out.toByteArray();
```

As the Java sound library is not supported in Android the above code containing the AudioInputStream object does not work in an Android application. Is there a corresponding way to do the above in Android?